# Truncate Laravel? Only newest rows

Tags: laravel, postgresql, eloquent

I would like to fetch only the newest rows in L5.5 with a truncate.

For example, my table is

```
ID  Name created
1   test xxxx-xx-xx
2   test xxxx-xx-xx
3   test1 xxxx-xx-xx
```

now i would like to get only unique rows (with name) - but the latest created row.

Is that possible with eloquent? The database i am using post postgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truncate has a very specific meaning in SQL and it's not what your looking for. Truncate will delete all records from the table.

What you want is to group the rows by name then order by latest. In Eloquent it would be

```
Model::latest()->groupBy('Name')->get();
```